# AngularJS "{{}}" insite title attribute isn't working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I using this HTML & AngularJS code:

```
<td class="domain-col" ng-init="msg='error message'">
    <span class="label label-warning" ng-show="page.ErrorCode == 11" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ msg }}">Error</span>
</td>
```

This code is working inside `ng-repeat` in order to generate rows in table. Each row in the table is represented with `page` object. Each page has `ErrorCode`.

On `ng-init` I converting the error code to user friendly UI message, which will be printed to `title` attribute.

The problem is that instead print the error message into `title` attribute, the value of this attribute became "{{ msg }}". The value of `title` attribute after running the code:

- **Actual**: "{{ msg }}" string.
- **Expected**: "error message".

Why this happens? How to fix this?

Comment: [works as expected](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPEQvZ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ng-attr-*="{{expression}}"` directive here, in which `*` means `attributeName`, So basically what it does is. evaluated `expression` from interpolate and add evaluated value in that attribute.

```
ng-attr-title="{{msg}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
ng-attr-title="{{msg}}"
```